# How general should exceptions be?

Tags: java, exception

In Java how general should my checked exceptions be?

Which of the following two examples should I be using more frequently: `UserNotFoundException` or `EntityNotFoundException` (generic input).

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably keep them as specific as possible. Other errors may occur that you did not intend, and therefore, don't know how to deal with. Only use general exceptions when you know exactly how you want to deal with them.

Answer (score 2):

Be as specific as you can.  The specificity only increases the amount of information available to the person debugging the error.  It is common practice to declare that a function throws a generalized exception, but when the code actually throws the exception, it throws a (possibly much) more specific exception which is a subclass of the exception that was declared.

Something like:

```
public void test() throws IOException
{
    if(openFile(FILE_NAME) == null) throw new FileNotFoundException("Check FILE_NAME.");
}
```

Comment: In other words, define both UserNFE and EntityNFE (with UserNFE extends EntityNFE) and throw the most specific exception you can. This allows the caller to handle the exception at the appropriate specificity.

Comment: On the other hand, having *too* many exceptions is also a common problem. Especially over time, when people like come up with 5 different exception classes that all mean the same, but slightly different.

Comment: @GhostCat: If the consuming code can reasonably be expected to want to respond to all of these different exception types in different ways, then it's still worthwhile to have them be different types. In cases where they just want blanket error handling logic, they can always *catch* a less-specific type of exception.